# react-virtualized - Is there a way to add hover style on rows of the Table

Tags: reactjs, react-virtualized

When we user hovers on the row, the background color of the respective row should change to #e7e7e7.

- Tried to add row effect through JSS, but this allows to have row effect on the cells instead of rows.
  [JSS approach](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LO5Ej.png)
- I tried to add hover effect using the props rowStyle, but this didn't work for me.
  [Using prop rowStyle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZdY9.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using styled-components in my project and this is how you can style the row using it.

```
const StyledTable = styled(Table)`
    .ReactVirtualized__Table__row {
        :hover {
            background: red;
        }
    }
`;
```

I think you're using the wrong selector.

What styling lib are you using?

Comment: This worked. My bad, I didn't tried using styled component. Was trying to override the style using makeStyles. Thanks.